# Exercise on Radon–Nikodym derivative

Tags: measure-theory, derivatives, radon-nikodym

Consider the measure space $(\mathbb{N}, P(\mathbb{N}))$  and two measures $\mu$ and $\nu$, where $\mu$ is the counting measure and $\nu$ is defined as
$$ \nu(E) = \sum_{n \in E}(n+1)$$

Compute $d\mu/d\nu$ if its possible.

--

How would you proceed?

Thanks in advice!

Julian

Answer (score 3):

By definition the Radon-Nikodym derivative is a function $f$ such that
$$\nu (E)=\int _Efd\mu,$$ in the counting measure this means
$$\nu (E)=\int _Efd\mu =\sum _{n\in E}f(n),$$
so is not $f(n)=n+1.$
**Edit:** Taking the inverse problem, $d\mu /d\nu =\frac{1}{n+1}.$

Comment: You calculated dν/dμ instead of dμ/dν, am I right?

Comment: @JulianVené You are right, forgive my blindness. :).

Comment: thanks for the solution!

Comment: @JulianVené You are welcome!